# Remove columns that contain a specific word

Tags: r

I have a data set that has 313 columns, ~52000 rows of information. I need to remove each column that contains the word "PERMISSIONS". I've tried grep and dplyr but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've read the file in,

```
testSet <- read.csv("/Users/.../data.csv")
```

Other examples show how to remove columns by name but I don't know how to handle wildcards. Not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do you mean remove columns where *the column name* includes `PERMISSIONS` or where *a string somewhere in the column data* includes `PERMISSIONS`?

Comment: the word "PERMISSIONS" is in the column names or in the rows within the columns (ie data)?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to just remove columns that are named `PERMISSIONS` then you can use the select function in the `dplyr` package.

```
df <- data.frame("PERMISSIONS" = c(1,2), "Col2" = c(1,4), "Col3" = c(1,2))

PERMISSIONS Col2 Col3
1    1    1
2    4    2

df_sub <- select(df, -contains("PERMISSIONS"))

Col2 Col3
1    1
4    2
```

Comment: I get this error  `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’`  and can't determine why.  Any advice?

Comment: If I need to exclude by multiple characters?

Answer (score 6):

From what I could understand from the question, the OP has a data frame like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
           a b c d
           e f PERMISSIONS g
           h i j k
           PERMISSIONS l m n',
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The goal is to remove every column that has any 'PERMISSIONS' entry. Assuming that there's no variability in 'PERMISSIONS', this code should work:

```
cols <- colSums(mapply('==', 'PERMISSIONS', df))
new.df <- df[,which(cols == 0)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
New.testSet <- testSet[,!grepl("PERMISSIONS", colnames(testSet))]
```

EDIT: changed script as per comment.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `grepl` with `!` negate,

```
New.testSet <- testSet[!grepl("PERMISSIONS",row.names(testSet)),
                         !grepl("PERMISSIONS", colnames(testSet))]
```

Comment: He wants columns that have "PERMISSIONS" anywhere in the rows to be dropped as well.

Comment: The OP has been asked twice to clarify this in the comments. As it is i feel its open to interpretation

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these answers only do part of what you want. I think this is what you're looking for. There is probably a better way to write this though.

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame("PERMISSIONS" = c(1,2), "Col2" = c("PERMISSIONS","A"), "Col3" = c(1,2))

  PERMISSIONS        Col2 Col3
1           1 PERMISSIONS    1
2           2           A    2

df = df[,!grepl("PERMISSIONS",colnames(df))]
setDT(df)
ind = df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("PERMISSIONS", x, perl=TRUE))] 
df[,which(colSums(ind) == 0), with = FALSE]

   Col3
1:    1
2:    2
```