# R - data cleaning and mutate errors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, mutate

I have reviewed [Error: Problem with `mutate()` column (...) must be size 15 or 1, not 17192](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185381/error-problem-with-mutate-column-must-be-size-15-or-1-not-17192), [How to drop columns with column names that contain specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346417/how-to-drop-columns-with-column-names-that-contain-specific-string), [Remove columns that contain a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815039/remove-columns-that-contain-a-specific-word), and associated error troubleshooting.

I have a large dataset with viral data for different species in different areas - sample data below

```
Country    ..2  Area    Site    ID      Species Sample    Original Sample/Specimen #
<chr>     <lgl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>
Tanzania    NA  UMNP    UMNPhq  AATPH   PG     Feces    AATPHF2 
Tanzania    NA  UMNP    UMNPhq  AATPI   PG     Feces    AATPIF2 
Tanzania    NA  UMNP    UMNPhq  AATPJ   PG     Feces    AATPJF2 
Tanzania    NA  UMNP    UMNPhq  ATTPK   PG     Feces    ATTPKF2 
Tanzania    NA  UMNP    UMNPhq  AATPL   PG     Feces    AATPLF2 

Filovirus (MOD) PCR  Date (Filo MOD)
<chr>                <date>
Indeterminant        2015-03-16
Indeterminant        2015-03-16
Indeterminant        2015-03-16
Indeterminant        2015-03-16
Negative             2015-03-16
```

I am trying to recode a viral status, positive or negative, for every sample id (just filovirus here, but there's a lot of them, so please help code more generally)

Code I've tried - first subsetting data to only include a specific area

```
viral <- subset(data, Area %in% "UMNP")
```

Here I got rid of unwanted columns and then was able to get infection status, but it converted all other information on the sample to "NA" causing additional error codes when I try to maintain the values.

```
viralres <- viral %>% 
     dplyr::select(-matches(c('Performed by ()', 'performed by', 'Date of', '1Performed by', 'Performed by', "Date ()", "...2"),)) %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, ~case_when(. == "Indeterminant" ~ "0", 
                                       . == "Negative" ~ "0", 
                                       . == "Positive" ~ "1"))
```

Dput

```
structure(list(Country = c("Tanzania", "Tanzania", "Tanzania", 
"Tanzania", "Tanzania"), ...2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Area = c("UMNP", 
"UMNP", "UMNP", "UMNP", "UMNP"), Site = c("UMNPhq", "UMNPhq", 
"UMNPhq", "UMNPhq", "UMNPhq"), `Animal ID` = c("AATPH", "AATPI", 
"AATPJ", "ATTPK", "AATPL"), Species = c("Procolobus gordonorum", 
"Procolobus gordonorum", "Procolobus gordonorum", "Procolobus gordonorum", 
"Procolobus gordonorum"), `Sample Type` = c("Feces", "Feces", 
"Feces", "Feces", "Feces"), `Original Sample/Specimen #` = c("AATPHF2", 
"AATPIF2", "AATPJF2", "ATTPKF2", "AATPLF2"), `Filovirus (MOD) PCR` = c("Indeterminant", 
"Indeterminant", "Indeterminant", "Indeterminant", "Negative"
), `Date (Filo MOD)` = structure(c(16510, 16510, 16510, 16510, 
16510), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `mutate_if(is.character, ...)` will change all of your character columns. It looks like the only column you are trying to change is "Filovirus (MOD) PCR". So you could change the command to

```
viral %>% 
  dplyr::select(-matches(c('Performed by ()', 'performed by', 'Date of', '1Performed by', 'Performed by', "Date ()", "...2"),)) %>%
  mutate(across(`Filovirus (MOD) PCR`, ~case_when(. == "Indeterminant" ~ "0", 
                                     . == "Negative" ~ "0", 
                                     . == "Positive" ~ "1")))
```

for the least amount of change. That way you are only changing that column. Alternatively you could more directly mutate that single column using `case_match`

```
viral %>% 
  dplyr::select(-matches(c('Performed by ()', 'performed by', 'Date of', '1Performed by', 'Performed by', "Date ()", "...2"),)) %>%
  mutate(`Filovirus (MOD) PCR` = case_match(`Filovirus (MOD) PCR`,"Indeterminant" ~ "0", 
                                     "Negative" ~ "0", 
                                     "Positive" ~ "1"))
```

Note that `case_match` was introduced in `dplyr 1.1.0`

Comment: This is just sample code, so yes, here it is only one column. However, in the larger dataset, it is many columns.

Comment: If it's many columns, then you can add them all to the `across()` call. You can either list them explicitly or come up with a more selective pattern that just `is.character` to identify them.

Comment: ```Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `~...`.
Caused by error:
! `~...` must be a vector, not a <formula> object.```

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Did you get that error with the test data you provided? If I copy/paste into R it works fine for me. What version of `dplyr` are you using?

Comment: I think I'm using dplyr 1.1.0, but I just updated my tidy verse I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_if`.

```
viralres <- viral %>% 
     dplyr::select(-matches(c('Performed by ()', 'performed by', 'Date of', '1Performed by', 'Performed by', "Date ()", "...2"),)) %>%
     mutate_at(c("Filovirus (MOD) PCR"), ~case_when(. == "Indeterminant" ~ "0",
                                                    . == "Negative" ~ "0", 
                                                    . == "Positive" ~ "1"))
```

In the first argument of `mutate_at`, add all your sample id (Filovirus, etc...) in a vector.

Comment: ```Error in `mutate_at()`:
! `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a
  <formula> object.```

Comment: Note that `mutate_at` has been superseded in newer versions of dplyr. The help page encourages the use of `across()` instead.

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah, good one !

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Strange because c() isn't formula object... replace the 'c' by 'vars' in the `mutate_at()`.

Comment: ```Warning: NAs introduced by coercionError in "Filovirus (MOD) PCR":"Phlebo (Sanchez-Seco) PCR" : 
  NA/NaN argument```